# Special URL formatting for Java Web Apps

Tags: java, tomcat, url-rewriting

Its best to just show what I'm trying to achieve. This isn't meant to be functional, just describe the problem.

Here's what my tomcat web app currently accepts...

```
  /.../mywebapp/doSomething.jsp?id=somenumber.
```

I want it to look like

```
  /.../mywebapp/somenumber
```

What is this concept called, and does anyone have a good resource on it ? I'd like to use pure java as much as possible, and avoid the use of apache-specific or 3rd party resources.

Comment: This is called servlet mapping you might look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234210/can-anyone-explain-servlet-mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *URL rewriting* and if you don't want to implement it using `mod_rewrite` (and Apache HTTPD), then you could use Tuckey's [`UrlRewriteFilter`](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), a Java Web Filter based on `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Hmm... which do you recommend ? Or, which is more common in real-world applications ?

Comment: @JHarnach Apache + mod\_rewrite is IMO the most efficient architecture (and will save some CPU cycles at the app server level) but also a bit more complex. If you don't have a dedicated box for Apache, if you don't want to use Apache, then Tuckey's filter is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

have you look at Codeigniter.net? it's php framework. it url style is just like what you want. What did CI use anyway?