# How to set up the root servlet in Tomcat 6?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6

Sorry for beginner's questions but I wonder how can I set the root servlet in Tomcat 6?
For example I want to access my servlet on

`localhost:8080`, not on

```
localhost:8080/myservlet
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

deploy an web app with context root `/`
and set servlet-mapping in web.xml as

```
<servlet-mapping>
  ..
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for reply but servlet's web.xml or server's?

Comment: @gennad application's `web.xml`

Comment: Oh, sorry, really application's. Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread, but Jigar Joshi's answer wasn't working for me on `Tomcat 8.0` and `Servlet 3.1`. So I used the following mapping in `web.xml`.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In section 12.2, [Servlet 3.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1496512160_9a90cc5a6c14c1548d00ed74bd6ab121) states that:

> The empty string ("") is a special UR L pattern that exactly maps to
>   the  application's context root, i.e., requests  of the form
>   http://host:port//. In this case the path info is  ’ /
>   ’  and the servlet path and context path is  empty string (““).

Comment: Works like charm

Answer (score 0):

I did the following in my web.xml. I mapped servlet as index.html.

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>myservlet</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and then the servlet itself:

```
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>myservlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>myservlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Tomcat 6 context configuration documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html):

> Context elements may be explicitly defined ... *(snip)* ... in individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the
>   `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/`
>   directory. The name of the file (less
>   the .xml extension) will be used as
>   the context path. Multi-level context
>   paths may be defined using #, e.g.
>   `foo#bar.xml` for a context path of
>   `/foo/bar`. **The default web
>   application may be defined by using a
>   file called `ROOT.xml`.**

You must also [map the servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234210/can-anyone-explain-servlet-mapping) in that application to the root path (`/`).