# Running servlet at correct location in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm using tomcat 7.0 and eclipse kepler.  When I deploy my servlets onto my server they are running at `/<Project Name>/<Servlet Name>` when I want them to run at `/<Servlet Name>`.  How can I change this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up the root servlet in Tomcat 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177047/how-to-set-up-the-root-servlet-in-tomcat-6)

Comment: See also: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `Context Root` name of your web application:

- Right Click on your project.
- Click on Properties.
- Choose "Web Project Settings".
- Change the Context Root property.
- Clean your server and restart it.