# Modifying home page of tomcat server while using servlets in java

Tags: java, tomcat, eclipse-luna

Hi I'm using **Eclipse Luna** and **Apache-Tomcat** server `8.0.15`.

When I run a `servlet` program in the web browser the path of the `servlet` has to mentioned.

For Example: `http://localhost:8080/DemoServletPrj/DemoServlet`

Is it possible that by just typing `http://localhost:8080` I can see my `servlet` running in the browser?

If so how do i go about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat 6: How to change the ROOT application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application)

Answer (score 0):

This is answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177047/how-to-set-up-the-root-servlet-in-tomcat-6).

Just find your web.xml in your site folder and change the root path;

```
<servlet-mapping>
  ..
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: here!!!! Where? If you have mentioned any link, plz update your ans and give some description about ans.