# Storing files of any-type in database

Tags: java, database

I am going to develop a portal in J2EE for students to upload and download data. Data can be any thing like PDF file, doc file, ppt file or can be Image or Video also.

How can i manage Data in database?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need all ground up. I will just give direction, you need work on it, and if there is a problem come with *specific* issue.

1. Upload files to your file system, or storage, or someplace like Amazon S3. For this use, something like [Apache FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)
2. Once upload is done, get the location of the file where you saved it on the storage-server. Say, `/mnt/media/uploads/file.extension`
3. Have your database with a table that stores the *metadata* about the file. In general it would look like:

   ```
   upload_id | file_name | file_location | user_id | timestamp
   ```

   where `upload_id` is the PK, `file_name` is the uploaded file's original name, `file_location` is the *actual full path* of the file where it resides in your storage, `user_id` is the uploader's Id, a FK from `users` table.
4. The display part: Have your logic to use this database to display `file_name`.
5. To download, you can have something like this [How to config Tomcat to serve images from an external folder outside webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417658/how-to-config-tomcat-to-serve-images-from-an-external-folder-outside-webapps) , note that this is not limited to serving image file. It can serve any type of file.

Now, you would wonder, why on earth am I doing so much painful things instead of just saving it as binary data in database? Well, I do not want to dive into discussion, I personally prefer this approach as I think *databases are for data, file-systems are for files*. See a good discussion here: [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you don't care what format the data is in (which is to say, you won't query the data at the database level), in which case you should look at the binary data types.

I can't be more specific without knowing what database back-end you're using, but some common names for this data type are `BLOB`, `binary`, `varbinary`, `raw` or `image`.

More here: http://onlamp.com/onlamp/2001/09/13/aboutSQL.html

Answer (score 0):

Store the file in the file system renamed to the record id where the file name is stored. This is less overhead and allows a better virus scanning; "you uploaded the xyz virus".

You can even do tricks like storing large files on another server. Backups are easier.