# Accessing files out of project directory in Grails

Tags: java, html, grails, web

I am doing a project that use a lot of videos to display in the gsp.
But i don't know how to access the files out of the grails project, the files are in /storage/media directory.
I'm trying this:

```
<video width="640" height="480" id="player" poster="/storage/media/play/Satisfaction - .png" controls="controls" preload="auto">
   <source type="video/mp4" src="/storage/media/play/Satisfaction - Play.mp4" />
```

But it isnt working.

Do someone know how to access it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this totally depends on how you deployed your application. you can configure apache web server or apache tomcat to serve static files from that directory or if you are using nginx you can let nginx serve all those videos.

see [how to configure tomcat to serve external static assets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417695/288652) or [read how to do it with nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location).