# Tomcat 404 for a folder in webapps

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a folder called attachments in my `webapps` folder in my `Apache Tomcat` directory, in which I need to save some files and images. When I'm giving the local path i.e. in `C:/` the files needed are being saved in the correct location.

However I need to load these images from the server at runtime so I'm trying to access the image by the localhost url `/attachments/img.png`. The image is not being found (`404 error`).

I tried opening Tomcat's `manager` to see if attachments is listed. It is there however when I click it a 404 error is being thrown too. Other deployed web applications are being found.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: This guy seemed to be trying to do the same thing, may be worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417658/how-to-config-tomcat-to-serve-images-from-an-external-folder-outside-webapps

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just create a folder in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps` like this and access it from web browser.

`webapps` folder is supposed to be home for all web applications with proper J2EE web app like directory structure e.g. `WEB-INF/web.xml`, `WEB-INF/classes`, `WEB-INF/lib`, `META-INF` etc.

[**Read more about Web Application Directory Stricture**](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Standard_Directory_Layout)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am still confused since yesterday I did the same exact things and tomcat did recognize the folder and the images were in fact loaded!

Comment: You can leverage [Virtual Webapp in Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Virtual_webapp) or see some answers in the provided link by @Kyle