# Tomcat 7 delete images from application when publish

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-rs

I have an application using JAX-RS. I upload and save images here :

```
C:\Java Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\wtpwebapps\myApp\images
```

Uploading works correctly using this code :

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

but problem is when I publish or sometimes restart server. All images are deleted after publish or sometimes restart of server.

Can anyone tell me solution for this problem ?

Comment: The problem is that you are storing your images under the wtpwebapps folder. You should store your images to a folder outside the webapp, as the webapp folder can be cleaned/republished.

Comment: outside the wtpwebapps  folder I can reach application via url ? or I need a method to get it  ?

Comment: You need a special servlet that will then serve the image for you from that location. In the past I have used Apache Web Server to front a Tomcat server and added an alias in Apache to serve the files.

Comment: Maybe you should use a http server like Apache for providing static resources.

Comment: This duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417658/how-to-config-tomcat-to-serve-images-from-an-external-folder-outside-webapps

Comment: Thank you :) I will write a method to "download" it and show in browser