# Using tileimages from static path in OL3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I had generated tile images using gdal2tiles. I am deploying my application in tomcat which is in C drive. Since tile images occupy more space, I had created a new drive E and placing all the images there. Now, can I use the tile images from E drive? if my images are in E: maps and my application is running in C: tomcat: OL3 how do I use images from E drive for my application running in C drive?

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                        url: '..../{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
                    })
                })
```

Comment: Create a new server pointing to those images. And use that server path to access images.

Comment: You mean do i need to create a new server in the same C drive?

Comment: Which kind server you are using?

Comment: Tomcat Apache..

Comment: You have to go through it. Hope it will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417658/how-to-config-tomcat-to-serve-images-from-an-external-folder-outside-webapps

Comment: Okay thanks. Let me look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create separate server pointing to image folder and use that server address to serve images in your current project. Hope it will solve your problem.