# Tomcat context docbase not working to serve static images

Tags: java, tomcat

I need to serve images directly from a folder outside war file using tomcat server.
I tried few options like setting the image location path in context docbase but its not working.
I configured that in server.xml of tomcat as follows

```xml
<Context docBase="E:\images\" path="/images" />
```

I need a solution directly from tomcat side and cant make any code changes to serve them.
Already gone through these links but of no use:
[How to config Tomcat to serve images from an external folder outside webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417658/how-to-config-tomcat-to-serve-images-from-an-external-folder-outside-webapps)

Tomcat version : 8.5, my images are in .svg format.
Please help me in this.

Comment: Did you try to use forward slashes in the docBase attribute like `E:/images/`

Comment: @DrHopfen tried that its not working

Answer (score 3):

This may help @Kirti or someone who is facing this problem.

I tried with following solution in same case in my project:-

1. I created a directory on server as `E:\MyProject\Images`
2. Added following `<Context />` tag in `server.xml` inside `<Host></Host>` tag

   `<Context docBase="E:\\MyProject\\Images" path="/images"/>`
3. Then I could simply access the images using following link:

   `http://localhost:8080/images/firstImage.jpg`

**Note:** For windows we separate path with \\ and in linux need to use //

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Closing slash of the context tag. Also forward slashes are preferable and work as well on Windows.

```
<Context docBase="E:/images/" path="/images" />
```

Comment: I have closed context as </context>

Comment: Do you see any log messages? What is the errornous behaviour?