# jQuery import not being found

Tags: jquery, spring, google-app-engine, spring-3

My ajax request is not being processed. I receive the warning when starting my server : 
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/jquery-1.7.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'. I think this is occuring because the file jquery-1.7.js is not being found.

```
<jsp:useBean id="message" scope="request" type="java.lang.String"/>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Spring MVC Ajax Demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.7.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function doAjax() {
      alert('here')
      $.ajax({

        url: 'time',
        data: ({name : "me"}),
        success: function(data) {
          $('#time').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
${message}
<button id="demo" onclick="doAjax()" title="Button">Get the time!</button>
<div id="time">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Do I need to amend the dispatcher entry -

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Update - this helped me : [Static files in (Java) App Engine not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026578/static-files-in-java-app-engine-not-accessible)

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? Looks simply like your dispatcher is trying to handle the request for a JS file and failing. The dispatcher should not really be handling static resources unless you specifically want it to. Simple answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add a `<static-files>` to `appengine-web.xml`, including jquery-1.7.js there, or you can get it from google, via

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'd prefer to use <static-files> in case I need to debug the jQuery. Is this correct - <static-files>
        <include path="/scripts/jquery-1.7.js" />
</static-files>
my jsp folder is int web-inf dir

Comment: I put JavaScript in war/js/ . Then `<include path="/js/foo.js" />`

Comment: But what do you use in your jsp to import the jQuery instead of -   <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script> ?

Comment: `<script ... src="js/foo.js"/></script>`