# JSP/Java table issue

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a table that is populated depending on how many cars are there. If the number of cars is 1 it will give me the 1 row (where 5 attributes are arranged in 5 columns). If the number of cars is 2 it will give me 2 rows(same 5 attributes), & so on. Now I need to split the table into as many cars are there so that there is just one row for every car. I need to do it in JSP and trying to use the tag `<c:choose>` or `<c:if>`, but isn't working . Please help

Comment: Maybe you should post the code that it's not working. That will help us to get a better understanding.

Comment: Are you really saying that if there are 500 cars (rows) in that table, you want it to create 500 tables?  It seems like you're trying to do something you probably shouldn't.

Comment: there won't be 500 cars. The maximum is 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `<c:forEach>` here. With it you can iterate over any `List<T>` and print the `<tr>` on every iteration. Assuming that you have populated a `List<Car>` and put it in the EL scope as `${cars}`, here's an example:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${cars}" var="car">
        <tr>
            <td>${car.make}</td>
            <td>${car.model}</td>
            <td>${car.type}</td>
            <td>${car.color}</td>
            <td>${car.price}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

#### See also:

- [Beginning and intermediate JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)
- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample code - Traversing an HTML Table with JavaScript and DOM Interfaces</title>
<script>
    function start() {
        // get the reference for the body
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
        var tbl     = document.createElement("table");
        var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        // creating all cells
        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            // creates a table row
            var row = document.createElement("tr");

            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
                // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
                // the end of the table row
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                var cellText = document.createTextNode("cell is row "+j+", column "+i);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }

            // add the row to the end of the table body
            tblBody.appendChild(row);
        }

        // put the <tbody> in the <table>
        tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
        // appends <table> into <body>
        body.appendChild(tbl);
        // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
        tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aren't you confusing Java/JSP with JavaScript? By the way, if you post someone else's code, it would be nice to add a [reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/traversing_an_html_table_with_javascript_and_dom_interfaces) instead of doing as if it's your own.