# Calling application.getRealPath() from within a class in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I am writing a class in JSP to retrieve a bunch of config values from an XML file. My plan is to have a class "XMLConfig" that loads in the values from the file, and then uses access methods to get at the values in the config object.

My problem is that i cannot seem to call application.getRealPath() from within the class, since eclipse tells me that "application cannot be resolved". I suspect that I must change "application" to something else but I am unsure what.

My code for the class:

```
<%!
//Config object
public class XMLConfig {

 public boolean loadConfigFile(String strName) {
  String XMLfileName = application.getRealPath(strName);
  try {
   DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = null;
   doc = db.parse(XMLFileName);
  }catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   return false;
  }
  return true;

 }
}
%>
```

Comment: Defining a class inside a JSP is bad practice. I strongly recommend you rewrite this as a servlet.

Comment: I can't get this code highlighting to work.
Anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Using `getRealPath()` is not highly recommended either as your webapp may not actually map to a real path on the file system depending on your servlet container.

Comment: I see, could you suggest a viable alternative?
Also, purely out of interest why does application.getRealPath() work outside of the class declaration, but not inside  it?

Comment: Because the application object is provided in the JSP context, our class is a sub-context. You can "fix" this by passing the application object as parameter to the `loadConfigFile()` method. (btw, `getRealPath()` is also present in the `ServletContext` interface.)

Comment: @rsp: `application` **IS** an instance of `ServletContext`.

Comment: @BalusC: Oops, lol. I seemed to remember that JSP's had both application and context passed into the page.

Comment: @rsp: maybe you're confusing it with `pageContext` which is an instance of `JspContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

application isn't a global var. If you want to use it in your method then you'll need to pass it as a parameter.

Not sure why you're defining the class within the jsp though instead of just creating a 'normal' java class.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I read up on importing my own java classes and now have the class in a separate .java file. The getRealPath() problem is not really an issue anymore, but this was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

That's a job for a servlet instead of JSP. Create a class which `extends` [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) and implement the `doGet()` method as follows:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String strName = getOrDefineItSomehow();
    Document doc = loadConfigFile(getServletContext().getRealPath(strName));
    // Do whatever you want with it and then display JSP page.
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/config.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Map this servlet in `web.xml` on an `url-pattern` of for example `/config` and invoke it by for example http://example.com/context/config. It'll run the code in `doGet()`.

#### See also:

- [Beginning and intermediate JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995)