# How to retrieve the name of checkbox in servlet if I provide dynamic names?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When I provide a dynamic name of checkbox inside a for loop like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<%=i%>" />
```

How can I retrieve the value in servlet?

Comment: Why do you need such a function ? Dynamic forms are a bad idea in Java web programming since you cannot map the form with a Java bean.
I'd rather preconize you a form with fields that can be hidden if you don't need them (with a dynamic "hidden" property and not a dynamic name).

Comment: @Benoit: they are only a bad idea if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Three ways:

1. Just rerun the same for loop in servlet as you did in JSP (you truly know the loop conditions) and do `request.getParameter(i)` on every iteration and if necessary add every parameter value to a `List<String>` so that you can easily process it afterwards.
2. Prefix the parameter name with a certain string, e.g. `name="foo${i}"`, grab all parameters by `request.getParameterMap()`, loop over it and determine if the `name.startsWith("foo")` and if necessary collect the matched values in a `List<String>`.
3. Just give all checkboxes the same name, but a different value and grab the checked ones by `request.getParameterValues("checkboxname");`. It will return a `String[]` with all values.

Way 3 is the normal practice by the way.

---

That said, *scriptlets* (those `<% %>` things in your code) indicates bad practices. I'd suggest to throw away the old fashioned JSP/Servlet books/tutorials you're currently reading and get yourself through the following links to learn how to do things properly:

- [Beginning and intermediate JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)
- [JSP/Servlet best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)