# Java:how to pass value from class/bean to servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

i am new to java, i'm having problem passing value from a class/bean (which are stored in arraylist) to servlet. any idea how can i achieve that? below is my code.

```
package myarraylist;

public class fypjdbClass {

String timezone;
String location;

public String getTimezone() {
    return timezone;
}
public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
    this.timezone = timezone;
}
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}


public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public fypjdbClass() {
    super();
    ArrayList<fypjdbClass> fypjdbList = new ArrayList<fypjdbClass>();
    this.timezone = timezone;
    this.location = location;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    //Establish connection to MySQL database
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/fypjdb";
    Connection connection=null;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
         // Load the database driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // Get a Connection to the database
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
        ArrayList<fypjdbClass> fypjdbList = new ArrayList<fypjdbClass>();
        //Select the data from the database
           String sql = "SELECT location,timezone FROM userclient";
        Statement s = connection.createStatement();
        //Create a PreparedStatement
        PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = stm.executeQuery();
        //rs = s.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next()){

            fypjdbClass f = new fypjdbClass(); 

            f.setTimezone(rs.getString("timezone"));
            f.setLocation(rs.getString("location"));

            fypjdbList.add( f);

        }



        for (int j = 0; j < fypjdbList.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(fypjdbList.get(j));

          }
        //To display the number of record in arraylist
        System.out.println("ArrayList contains " + fypjdbList.size() + " key value pair.");


        rs.close ();
        s.close ();
        }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception is ;"+e);
        }

}
}
```

And this is the Servlet

```
package myarraylist;

public class arraylistforfypjServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public arraylistforfypjServlet() {
    super();
}

public static ArrayList<fypjdbClass> fypjdbList = new ArrayList<fypjdbClass>();

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    //processRequest(request, response); 

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/DataPage.jsp"); //You could give a relative URL, I'm just using absolute for a clear example.
    ArrayList<fypjdbClass> fypjdbList = new ArrayList<fypjdbClass>();// You can use any type of object you like here, Strings, Custom objects, in fact any object.
    request.setAttribute("fypjdbList", fypjdbList);
    rd.forward(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    //processRequest(request, response);
    doGet(request,response);
}

}
```

i dont know if my code is right, pls advise me. thanks lot ^^

Comment: you're storing your array in a request, after the method is executed in a servlet `doGet()` or `doPost()`, the request is cleared. Why not save it in Session? (`request.getSession().setAttribute(....)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't pass something into a servlet. You just let the servlet access something.

You should get rid of that `main()` method and move the database interaction code into a DAO class. I'd also give the model class (with timezone and location) a more sensitive name starting with an uppercase. So all with all, you should update the code so that it look something like the following:

Model class, the `Area` (name it whatever you want, as long as it makes sense), it should just represent a single entity:

```
public class Area {
    private String location;
    private String timezone;

    public String getLocation() { return location; }
    public String getTimezone() { return timezone; }

    public void setLocation(String location) { this.location = location; }
    public void setTimezone(String timezone) { this.timezone = timezone; }
}
```

Basic connection manager class, the `Database`, here you load the driver just once and provide a getter for the connection:

```
public class Database {
    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Database(String driver, String url, String username, String password) {
        try { 
            Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Driver class is missing in classpath", e);
        }
        this.url = url;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }
}
```

DAO class, the `AreaDAO`, here you put all DB interaction methods:

```
public class AreaDAO {
    private Database database;

    public AreaDAO(Database database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public List<Area> list() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        List<Area> areas = new ArrayList<Area>();

        try {
            connection = database.getConnection();
            statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT location, timezone FROM userclient");
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Area area = new Area();
                area.setLocation(resultSet.getString("location"));
                area.setTimezone(resultSet.getString("timezone"));
                areas.add(area);
            }
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        }

        return areas;
    }
}
```

Finally, in the servlet initialize the DAO once and obtain the list in the HTTP method:

```
public class AreaServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private AreaDAO areaDAO;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname";
        String username = "user";
        String password = "pass";
        Database database = new Database(driver, url, username, password);
        this.areaDAO = new AreaDAO(database);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            List<Area> areas = areaDAO.list();
            request.setAttribute("areas", areas);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/areas.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Cannot retrieve areas", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Map this servlet on an `url-pattern` of `/areas` in `web.xml` so that you can invoke it by http://example.com/contextname/areas

The `/WEB-INF/areas.jsp` can look like something this, assuming that you want to display the areas in a table:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${areas}" var="area">
        <tr>
            <td>${area.location}</td>
            <td>${area.timezone}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

#### See also:

- [Beginning and intermediate JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)
- [Advanced JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/msajsp.html)
- [DAO tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) (contains more advanced/flexible DAO examples)
- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995)

Comment: Great answer! Your code clearly reveals MVC pattern. Thanks for  posting such an excellent answer for a beginner to start with

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to load data from a database into the *fypjdbList* ArrayList in your servlet.

It isn't working because your servlet is not calling the database code. Your database code is in the `main` method of fypjdbClass; the `main` method is generally used by Java console or desktop applications but not in a Java servlet application.

A better way to retrieve data from the database is to create a Data Access Object (DAO). This is a Java class that contains only code to access the database. The DAO retrieves data for you, but does not store data itself (it would not contain `timezone` or `location`). The concept of a DAO is explained at http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html

Google will find you a number of tutorial on DAOs (I can't post the links here because as a new member of Stack Overflow I can only post one link!)

Writing servlets is useful when learning Java, but if you want to build a full website you will probably find it easier to use a framework like the Spring MVC (part of the Spring Framework). Spring MVC has a comprehensive step-by-step tutorial available which is very useful if you're new to Java web development.

Answer (score 0):

Why to confuse a newbie with different patterns!
@OP - Change your main() method to return data instead of void and create an instance for that class in the servlet.