# Clean URLs using jsp/ servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am planning to make a CMS using jsp and servlets. Could anyone tell me how to implement clean urls using this technologies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using urlrewritefilter: http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/. This uses a servlet filter and an xml-file to allow your application to have clean url's. The construction of the clean url's would be your own responsibility.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of `HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()` in the servlet which is acting as front controller.

Kickoff example without any trivial validation:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF" + request.getPathInfo() + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

This will make a request on for example http://example.com/context/servlet/foo/bar to display the `/WEB-INF/foo/bar.jsp` file. The JSP files should be placed in `/WEB-INF` to prevent them from direct access.

#### See also:

- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995)

Answer (score 0):

Use `URLRewriteFilter` or you can write it by yourself, it's quite simple if you know how to use deployment descriptor and filter.
For example, you have a servlet that responses content based on request parameter such as *a.com?**cat**=book&**post**=java* (call it `showContent servlet`)
and you want to rewrite the url to `a.com/book/java`
so you should create a filter:
filter name: dispatcher
mapping: /*

and in that filter, you should handle the string `"/book/java"` to generate data for **cat** and **post** variables. Then just forward it to the `showContent servlet` to handle the request.

Answer (score -1):

I use the JSTL <c:url> tag

Comment: How <c:url> helps with friendlier URLs?!