# show different url

Tags: tomcat, servlets, url-rewriting

I'm using tomcat and have a couple jsp pages. I'm wondering if it's possible to show a different url other than real patch(folder structure) in browser.
for example.
`www.abc.com/test/test.jsp` (this is real path)
display is as `www.abc.com/welcome`

so when user enter `www.abc.com/welcome`, he/she will actually see the test.jsp page

I know there is urlrewriter which i tried already, it bascially redirect to another page. i guess it's not helpful in my case.

any suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clean URLs using jsp/ servlets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528303/clean-urls-using-jsp-servlets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, you have a file name `pretty-config.xml`.

With this file you can show a different url other than real patch.

**Example:**

```
<url-mapping id="site"> 
   <pattern value="/mySite/" /> 
   <view-id value="/faces/sites/mySite.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

With these two simple lines of configuration, the user sees: pattern="/mySite/" in the browser URL and in the output HTML, but the server is actually rendering the resource: /faces/sites/mySite.jsf 
the actual location of the page on the server.

You can find information [here](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/)

Comment: this sounds great, i will try later today and get back here

Comment: No problem. Tell me if its work for you. If its work, you can up vote and accept the answer :).

Comment: PrettyFaces is for JSF only. OP is not using JSF. You need [Rewrite](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/) (which is still beta; these days [Tuckey's URLRewriteFilter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) is the best available).

Comment: @BalusC, he said that he have couple of jsp pages so he might think about JSF. JSF can use JSPs for its view, becuase JSF is a standardized Java framework for web UIs based on an MVC pattern.

Comment: It's only going to be a major change (in the good direction, I won't argue that :) ).

Comment: ok i tried, but keep getting error, looks like i have to install JSF on existing tomcat, which complicates the current case. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I dont have experience with JSF, and Tuckey's URLRwriterFilter seems redirecting to another url which has to be mapped to different page on server. so that means for the url there must be another page.  correct me if im wrong,because that what happened to me when testing URLRewriterFilter

Comment: ok, i cant find a better way to do it, eventually i have to make a servlet that output jsp in order to accomplish my goal

Comment: In jsf the life is easier... :)