# Converting URLs to have same output

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, url, post

We have a URL: http://example.com/index.jsp?hello=1&bye=0 where"1" and "0" are values of the parameter

How can I convert the URL to http://example.com/index.jsp/1/0 using form POST methods and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Url rewriting is what you are looking for.

[This](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/),
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563799/how-to-rewrite-url-in-tomcat-6) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528303/clean-urls-using-jsp-servlets) might help you.