# Should session be used to handle error message for form validation?

Tags: java, jsp, session, error-handling

I'm creating registration page and I've done basic client side (JS) form validation.
Now I am to write server side validation.

What I have done is call request.getParameter():

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
```

Then if the username input is not valid, I put error message to ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
errors.add("username is not valid");
```

Then, add the ArrayList object to session variable,

```
session.setAttribute("inputErrors", errors);
```

This way I can use logic to see if the ArrayList is not empty (i.e. there is an error),
redirect back to registration page and get the session value to display proper error message.

But I am wondering if using session this way is good way for handling error messages.
Since this operation only involves 2 pages: registration UI (regis.jsp) and the page that handles registration input validation and processing (process_regis.jsp) for instance.
My understanding of session is to be used across multiple pages mainly for logged-in user data.

please let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server side session is been shared among all requests from the same client session. The session lives as long as the user accesses the site for the first time until the session is been expired (not used over 30 minutes (which is configureable)), or it is been explicitly invalidated. With your approach, open the same page in a new browser tab. You would still see the error messages while the form in the new page isn't entered/submitted at all. This is not good for user experience.

The normal practice is to store the error messages in the request scope and **forward** the request to the same page instead of redirecting to it. This is easy if you use a fullworthy Servlet class instead of a JSP file for processing and validating. E.g.

`/WEB-INF/register.jsp`

```
<form method="post" action="register">
    <p><label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.username)}">
    <span class="error">${messages.username}</span>
    <p><label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <span class="error">${messages.password}</span>
    <p><label for="confirm">Confirm password <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="password" id="confirm" name="confirm">
    <span class="error">${messages.confirm}</span>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Register">
    <p>${messages.result}</p>
</form>
```

`com.example.RegisterServlet`

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();
    request.setAttribute("messages", messages); // Will be available by ${messages}.

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    if (username == null  || username.trim().isEmpty()) {
        messages.put("username", "Please enter username");
    }

    // ...

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Map this servlet as follows in `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>registerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>registerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Open it by http://example.com/context/register and go ahead.

#### See also

- [Beginning and intermediate JSP/Servlet tutorial](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)
- [DAO Tutorial - Use in JSP/Servlet (covers "Register User" use case)](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-use-in-jspservlet.html)
- [Servlet instantiation and session variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables/3106909#3106909)
- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: thanks for the description, it's good to know how to take advantage of web.xml

Comment: You're welcome. It's by the way not specifically `web.xml` which is advantageous. It's the Servlet :)

Comment: +1, nice example that shows servlets are a fine web framework themselves. At least they don't get in your way.

Comment: @BalusC: So if I have a jsp page home.jsp and I want to add a link to the register.jsp you posted above, how do I do that because in home.jsp, if I have <a> tag with href="/WEB-INF/register.jsp", it returns 404. I was thinking to create another servlet just to forward to the register.jsp? But this sounds not right.

Comment: To be clear, home.jsp --> invoke servlet that just forward the request to /WEB-INF/register.jsp so this servlet only has few line of code and if I do that, I have to create this type of simple-forward-only servlets if I want to add more pages under WEB-INF.

Comment: Just link to the servlet on the same URL as you call it by the browser: `<a href="register">`. Its `doGet()` will be called then.