# relative url and absolute url difference

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

What is the difference between relative and absolute url in servlet container. for example  if there is an jsp called forum.jsp under webinf folder. when i want dispatch the current request to the jsp from the current jsp file which is under the same webinf folder, is the following correct way

/forum.jsp

relative url means relative to the web-inf folder or to the jsp location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Absolute URL](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html)** is : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591899/relative-url-and-absolute-url-difference`

and a **relative URL** is: `/questions/3591899/relative-url-and-absolute-url-difference`

Also, a **[relative URL](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html)** can be just: `../questions/3591899/relative-url-and-absolute-url-difference` depending where is the linking page located...

Or `./3591899/relative-url-and-absolute-url-difference` if the linking page is located on the `questions` folder

I will suggest to always use [Relative URL](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html)... and it goes hard, keep trying to use them...

---

One question, why your JSPs are in the `WEB-INF/` folder?

You don't have access to `JSP` under the `WEB-INF` folder, if you try to access it the server will throw a `404 error`. `J2EE` only looks for classes and libraries under this folder.

Comment: The last part of your answer is wrong. The `RequestDispatcher` can perfectly access resources in `/WEB-INF`. The intent of placing JSP files there is to hide them from **direct access** (as you say, you will get a 404) so that the enduser is forced to use a servlet to request the JSP file. This has more advantages like ability to use SEO friendly URL's, the frontcontroller pattern, the MVC pattern, etcetera. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995).

Comment: Things in WEB-INF and its sub folders are not accessible directly from client, but it works well when you dispatch it (forward or redirect)

Answer (score 1):

An absolute URL is an URL which includes the scheme (e.g. `http:`). A relative URL does not include the scheme and is thus dependent on the current context.

How to interpret a relative URL is a bit more complicated. It depends entirely on the context where the URL is been used. E.g. in a webbrowser, or in a servlet, or even in the local disk file system (`java.io.File` and so on).

When talking in the servlet context, when a relative URL starts with `/`, it will be relative to the context root (i.e. the root of the webcontent folder, there where the `/WEB-INF` folder is and where all JSP files are been placed).

So when you want to forward the request to `/WEB-INF/forums.jsp`, then you just specify that so:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/forums.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

But when a relative URL doesn't start with `/`, then it will be relative to the current request URL. So when the request URL is for example http://example.com/context/servlets/servletname and you use the relative URL `forums.jsp`, then the following

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("forums.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

will actually point to http://example.com/context/servlets/forums.jsp