# view data form database table to table tag in jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to apply MVC2 J2EE approach in my work with JSP pages.
I want to separate the code in Servlet and design in JSP.
The problem I am facing is that I want to display all users and their data from DB table 
to HTML table in JSP page 
Now How should I call the servlet from JSP page, since there is no form in display page
and I don't know whether I could use dispatcher since the admin will click on `<a href>display users` and JSP pages should display all uesrs. How can i make that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `doGet()` method of the Servlet and call the URL of the servlet instead.

E.g.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<User> users = userDAO.list();
    request.setAttribute("users", users);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/users.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Map this servlet in `web.xml` as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>users</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.UsersServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>users</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/users</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now the servlet is accessible by http://example.com/context/users.

In the `/WEB-INF/users.jsp` file use JSTL `c:forEach` to display users in a table.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
        <tr>
            <td>${user.name}</td>
            <td>${user.email}</td>
            <td>${user.age}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

The JSP file is to be placed in `/WEB-INF` folder to avoid that it's accessible without calling the servlet first.

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet)
- [(Advanced) design patterns in JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications)

---

**Update**: to install JSTL, take the following steps:

1. Download [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar).
2. Drop it in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. Do NOT extract it! Do NOT change `web.xml`! Some poor online tutorials will suggest this. They're all wrong.
3. Declare the taglib of interest in top of JSP page as per the [JSTL TLD documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/). For example, [JSTL core](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html):

   ```
     <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   ```

Comment: when i use </c:forEach> it makes error so i download JSTL_imp jar file and JSTL_api jar file and add it to my project , but </c:forEach> didn't recognize yet

Comment: See update in answer. I assume you're using a Servlet 2.5 container (e.g. Tomcat 6.x and up) and that your `web.xml` is declared as Servlet 2.5.

Comment: can u tell me what is user in servlet mapping
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>users</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/users</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
Is it MY JSP page?

Comment: for each now is work very well thanx , plz see the other comment .