# Sending parameter with JSP bean accessor

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have a bean called EmployeeRoster:

```
public class EmployeeRoster {
  protected List<Employee> janitors;
  protected List<Employee> teachers;
}
```

In JSP, I want to access the different lists of Employees by type. I know that I can do something like:

```
${employeeRoster.getJanitors}
```

However, I have many different types of employees and rather than creating an accessor in the EmployeeRoster for every type, I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
${employeeRoster.get(EmployeeType.JANITOR)}  // obviously, not valid
```

Is this possible in JSP? Can I apply a parameter to a bean accessor call?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a `Map<String, List<Employee>>` property. E.g.

```
public class EmployeeRoster {
    private Map<String, List<Employee>> types = new HashMap<String, List<Employee>>();

    public EmployeeRoster() {
        // Fill the map here?
    }

    // Add/generate getter.
}
```

You can then access the map value as follows:

```
${employeeRoster.types.janitor}
```

which basically does the same as `employeeRoster.getTypes().get("janitor")`. You can also use a dynamic key using the brace notation:

```
${employeeRoster.types[type]}
```

which does basically `employeeRoster.getTypes().get(type)`.

#### See also:

- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995)