# stable parameters in jsp page

Tags: jsp

I build a web application using jsp. I send parameters from servlet to jsp in get method to display them in jsp page when I request it. the problem is : when I submit the form to servlet and then return to jsp I have to send these parameter with the request.
How can I make a stable parameters so, I have to send them once (in get method only) and maintain them in jsp.

Comment: I can't for life of me understand what you mean. Please elaborate.

Comment: I want to maintain the parameter of the last request(from servlet to jsp) in jsp page so, when I send another request (from jsp to servlet) and return back to jsp, I do not lose the last parameters. I use the last parameter to display items in a list so, I want to maintain them in jsp

Answer (score 1):

You could access request parameters by ${param}.

```
<input name="foo" value="${param.foo}">
```

...

```
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="a" ${param.bar == 'a' ? 'checked' : ''}>
```

...

```
<select name="baz"> 
<option value="b" ${param.baz == 'b' ? 'selected' : ''}>label</option>
```

...

```
 <textarea name="boo">${param.boo}</textarea>
```

This basically prints request.getParameter("foo") as input value. This way the submitted value will be retained in the input elements.

same question here
[How can I retain HTML form field values in JSP after submitting form to Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937624/how-can-i-keep-jsp-form-fields-values-in-the-form-after-submit-thr-form)

Comment: I want to maintain the parameters sent from servlet to jsp, not the fields values

Comment: Please post such items as comments, not answers.

Comment: @ Dev developer - first u send parameters form servlet to info , then submit the form from jsp to servlet, so $param will solve ur problem.