# Access and print HTTP request query string parameters via EL in JSP page

Tags: jsp, el, http-request-parameters

I need to pass a request parameter from one JSP to another JSP page like this:

```
<a href="cv.jsp?type=alaacv">alaa</a>
```

However, when I try to access it as below, it doesn't print anything.

```
<c:set var="selectedCV" value="${type}" scope="request" />
<c:out value="${selectedCV}" />
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access it by `${param}` which is an [implicit EL object](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij) referring to the request parameter map (which is actually a `Map<String, String>`; if you need the `Map<String, String[]>` for multi-valued parameters, use `${paramValues}` instead).

```
<c:set var="selectedCV" value="${param.type}" />
<c:out value="${selectedCV}" />
```

The `${param.type}` basically resolves to `request.getParameter("type")`.

You can also just do as below without the need for `<c:set>`:

```
<c:out value="${param.type}" />
```

#### See also:

- [How to access objects in EL expression language ${}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387174/how-to-access-objects-in-el-expression-language)
- [How can I retain HTML form field values in JSP after submitting form to Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937624/how-can-i-retain-html-form-field-values-in-jsp-after-submitting-form-to-servlet)
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: it's not working too ?? do u think the problem is here <a href="CVs.jsp?type=alaacv"> ?

Comment: Then you've a typo or you aren't running the code you think you're running.

Comment: It works when I make like this
<c:out value="${param.type}" />
but doesn't work when I make like this
c:out value="${selectedCV}" />
???

Comment: Then your `<c:set>` was wrong. It needs to be definied exactly as in my answer, *before* the `<c:out>` in the *same* page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the given parameter in response object to the second `.jsp`. How to do that depends on the servlet/framework you are using (unless the framework should somehow do it automatically).

Comment: I am not using servlet, I know it's easier but right now I need to make simple request form jsp to another jsp page and send parameter through anchor !!

Comment: @Alaa - actually, you *are* using a servlet framework under the hood.  The servlet framework underpins JSPs.  However, I don't think this answer is on the right track.

Comment: I knew that when jsp:engine parse the jsp page it creates servlet for each page