# How to transfer data from JSP to servlet when submitting HTML form

Tags: jsp, servlets, forms

I have a JSP page with an HTML form:

```
<form action="SERVLET">
    <input type="text" name="name"/><br>        
    <input type="text" name="group"/>
    <input type="text" name="pass"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">            
</form>
```

How to obtain these data in a servlet and add them to database?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Create a class which extends [`HttpServlet`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservlet) and put [`@WebServlet`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/annotation/webservlet) annotation on it containing the desired URL the servlet should listen on.

```
@WebServlet("/yourServletURL")
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {}
```

And just let `<form action>` [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa) to this URL. I would also [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/doget-and-dopost-in-servlets) to use POST method for non-idempotent requests. You should make sure that you have specified the `name` attribute of the HTML form input fields (`<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>`). This represents the HTTP request parameter name. Finally, you also need to make sure that the input fields of interest are enclosed inside the desired form and thus not outside.

Here are some examples of various [HTML form input fields](https://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/forms/):

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/yourServletURL" method="post">
    <p>Normal text field.        
    <input type="text" name="name" /></p>

    <p>Secret text field.        
    <input type="password" name="pass" /></p>

    <p>Single-selection radiobuttons.        
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="Mr" /> Mr
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="Ms" /> Ms
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="Mx" /> Mx</p>

    <p>Single-selection checkbox.
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" /> Agree?</p>

    <p>Multi-selection checkboxes.
    <input type="checkbox" name="role" value="USER" /> User
    <input type="checkbox" name="role" value="ADMIN" /> Admin</p>

    <p>Single-selection dropdown.
    <select name="countryCode">
        <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
    </select></p>

    <p>Multi-selection listbox.
    <select name="animalId" multiple="true" size="2">
        <option value="1">Cat</option>
        <option value="2">Dog</option>
    </select></p>

    <p>Text area.
    <textarea name="message"></textarea></p>

    <p>Submit button.
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

    <p>Cancel button.
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" /></p>
</form>
```

Create a [`doPost()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservlet#doPost(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)) method in your servlet which grabs the submitted input values as request parameters keyed by the input field's `name` (**not** `id`!). You can use `request.getParameter()` to get submitted value from single-value fields and `request.getParameterValues()` to get submitted values from multi-value fields.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    String title = request.getParameter("title");
    boolean agree = request.getParameter("agree") != null;
    String[] roles = request.getParameterValues("role");
    String countryCode = request.getParameter("countryCode");
    String[] animalIds = request.getParameterValues("animalId");
    String message = request.getParameter("message");
    boolean submitButtonPressed = request.getParameter("submit") != null;
    boolean cancelButtonPressed = request.getParameter("cancel") != null;
    // ...
}
```

Do if necessary some [validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464931/how-perform-validation-and-display-error-message-in-same-form-in-jsp/) and finally persist it in the DB the usual [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)/[DAO](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) way.

```
User user = new User(name, pass, roles);
userDAO.save(user);
```

#### See also:

- [HTML beginner tutorial](https://htmldog.com/guides/html/)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [doGet and doPost in Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/doget-and-dopost-in-servlets)
- [How do I call a specific Java method on a click/submit event of a specific button in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723812/how-do-i-call-a-specific-java-method-on-click-submit-event-of-specific-button-in)
- [How perform validation and display error message in same form in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464931/how-perform-validation-and-display-error-message-in-same-form-in-jsp/)
- [How can I retain HTML form field values in JSP after submitting form to Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937624/how-can-i-retain-html-form-field-values-in-jsp-after-submitting-form-to-servlet)
- [How can I upload files to a server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)
- [Show JDBC ResultSet in HTML in JSP page using MVC and DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/show-jdbc-resultset-in-html-table-in-jsp-page-using-mvc-pattern)
- [Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa)

Comment: This was the piece of code I was looking for: `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` in the form action

Comment: How do you compile the above java code using javac?

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are plenty of database tutorials online for java (what you're looking for is called JDBC).  But if you are using plain servlets, you will have a class that extends `HttpServlet` and inside it you will have two methods that look like

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){

}
```

and

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){

}
```

One of them is called to handle `GET` operations and another is used to handle `POST` operations.  You will then use the `HttpServletRequest` object to get the parameters that were passed as part of the form like so:

```
String name = req.getParameter("name");
```

Then, once you have the data from the form, it's relatively easy to add it to a database using a JDBC tutorial that is widely available on the web.  I also suggest searching for a basic Java servlet tutorial to get you started.  It's very easy, although there are a number of steps that need to be configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

http://oreilly.com/catalog/javacook/chapter/ch18.html

Search for :

"Problem

You want to process the data from an HTML form in a servlet. "

Answer (score -2):

first up on create your jsp file :
and write the text field which you want
for ex:

after that create your servlet class:

```
public class test{

protected void doGet(paramter , paramter){

String name  = request.getparameter("name");
 }

}
```

Comment: How exactly does this contribute on top of already given answers? In other words, why exactly are you basically repeating an already given answer? Stack Overflow is a Q&A site where everyone can post answers and vote each other upon agreement. Stack Overflow is not an old fashioned discussion forum wherein everyone repeats each other into an undigestable mess upon agreement. Stack Overflow makes finding good answers easier this way.

Comment: we had this information in the previous answer that was accepted.