# Email validation in form using JSTL/JSP

Tags: html, forms, validation, jsp, jstl

I am currently working on a web application as a part of my project and I'm stuck here! It keeps saying. I don't know much about it but I would be glad if someone can help me with a basic email validation. So far, I've been able to ensure that none of the fields in the form remain empty. Thanks!

Comment: JSP/JSTL is just a HTML code generator. Do the job in normal Java  instead (usually, a servlet). See also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464931

Comment: can you explain a bit more? I am still pretty new to this. I have done form validations in the past using javascript but not using JSP. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Just follow the duplicate link in top of question and in above comment (and if necessary all links therein). By the way, JavaScript code is manipulatable by enduser. You should not rely on solely it for business critical validation.