# Using the Javascript variable in a JSP File

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a variable inside the javascript `document.ready` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var xxxx= $("#yyyy").val();
        alert(xxxx);
    });
</script>
```

I want to use the above `xxxx` variable in a JSP file. This is my JSP code which did not work:

```
<c:choose>   
    <c:when test="${xxxx == 'type'}">
        ........
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        .......
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Pleaase suggest me the method to use a javascript variable in a JSP file.

Comment: I think this may answer your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390832/how-to-use-javascript-in-jsp

Comment: Server-side logic shouldn't work with client-side code, unless you are constructing a hacking challenge :)