# Spring - from JSON response to webPage

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp, web

I have built a simple service in Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Person> eventList() throws ParseException {
    return personDAOImpl.list();
}
```

When I invoke the corresponding URL, I see a JsonObject list like this:

```
[{"id":2,"name":"John"},{"id":3,"name":"Jack"},{"id":4,"name":"Sam"}]
```

This service will be invoked both from a mobile app (and I know how to use a Json response in this case) and from a browser, and so I want that the /list service returns a Json.

By now, if I write the url in a browser (typing localhost:8080/myproject/eventList) I simply obtain the aforementioned Json String displayed on the screen.

How could I obtain a user-friendly interface that shows to the user a more friendly, like if I used a jsp?

ps: I have already used a service that successfully returns a jsp page (using ModelAndView), and that shows a table with the items, but I repeat that I would like to get a json response and than parsing it in a different way depending from the client (web browser or mobile app).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could build a client app which makes requests to your API [using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390832/how-to-use-javascript-in-jsp).

For example,

1. localhost:8080/jsp/home returns a jsp page Home.
2. The Home page makes AJAX request (using JavaScript) to localhost:8080/myproject/eventList and recieves the JSON object. [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)
3. The Home page adds (using JavaScript) some visual elements to html. [jQuery.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

That's all.