# How Can I Call a Javascript Function from an If Condition in my JSP?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have written 2 functions that hides and shows elements based on ID's. Now I have to pull a value from a java class, check to see if it's applicable, and then call one of the two functions to determine what it shown.

The debugger shows it hitting the if condition, and then skipping over it entirely. I can see that the value is stored in the variable.

```
    String showHideDeets = myData.showHideDeets();
    if(showHideDeets){
    %>
            <script>
            alert(showHideDeets);
            showTable("schollTable");
            showTable("selectionRow11");
            showTable("addrow");    
            </script>
    <%
    }
    else{
    %>
            <script>
            alert(showHideDeets);
            
            hideTable("schollTable");
            hideTable("selectionRow11");
            hideTable("addrow");    
            </script>   
    <%
    }
    %>
```

Comment: You can not call JavaScript function in if statement of JSP, because JSP is executed at the server side and JavaScript is executed at client side.

Comment: OK, so let me rephrase my question because I can't seemingly figure this out. How would I go about hiding those elements I'm trying to hide on the JSP page based on the values I'm grabbing? I obviously can't use javascript or jQuery which are the most common solutions.

Comment: May be this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20392048/7743705

Comment: @JackParker2 from JSP, you simply have to add style="display:none"

Comment: `showHideDeets` is a `String`. You can't use it like a boolean in an `if` statement.

Comment: That was a typo from taking the code from my corporate code base and putting it here, sorry.

Comment: @JackParker2 So it's a boolean?

Comment: It's a string it's meant to be .equals("Y");