# Sending post data from JSP to a Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to send data from a JSP file to a Java Servlet. I've seen so many examples on here on how to do it, and I believe I am doing it the right way, but for some reason the doPost() methods is not being called inside my servlet.

Here is what I added to my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   version="2.5">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>src.action.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is my JSP file

```
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>

        <form action = "localhost:8080/UserModule/src/action/login" method="post">
            Username<input type = "text" name = "username"><br><br>
            Password<input type = "password" name = "password"><br><br>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Here is my Java servlet:

```
   package action;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LoginServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String username = (request.getAttribute("username")).toString();
        System.out.println("asd");

        String password = (String) request.getAttribute("password");
        System.out.println(username);
    }

}
```

It's giving me an error on `import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;` and on `@WebServlet("/login")`

It's because they were only implemented in the spec v3.0, while I am only allowed to use spec v2.5 (required to at work).
Anyone has any idea how to solve this issue?

My directory:

[image]

Comment: here is your [Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971877/how-to-transfer-data-from-jsp-to-servlet) u get all the  important information from given link

Comment: I saw this thread Parth, but it didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I could see multiple errors in your post ,

1. Replace the action attribute with ,

   `<form action = "./login" method="post">`
2. If your using the version 2.5 , remove the import for annotation and also this line,

   `@WebServlet("/login")`
3. Thirdly, to access the `<form>` elements in the servlet , use [`request#getParameter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

   `String username = request.getParameter("username"));`

Comment: When I do <form action = "./login" method="post"> it redirects to localhost:8080/UserModule/WebContent/jsp/login which doesn't exist. My Servlet is in the same project, but under a different directory and package.

Comment: @Obviously use a `./login` in the action attribute

Comment: I did set ./login in the action attribute like this:  `<form action = "./login" method="post">`

Comment: is this valid path `<servlet-class>src.action.LoginServlet</servlet-class>` of your servlet . post your directory structure in your question

Comment: I fixed this issue. It's still not working. Anyway, I posted my directory structure in my question. Thanks.

Comment: @Obviously Can you add the pic here . restricted site for my network

Comment: I would, but it doesn't let me because I have less than 10 reputation.

Comment: where have you placed your servlet in the project ? And what error you are getting now ? is that 404 ?>

Comment: UserModule is my project.

I have a folder called src under it, with four packages under that named action, bo, dao, and vo. My servlet is inside action.

I have another folder under UserModule called jsp, with my jsp file in it.

WEB-INF is also under UserModule, and it has web.xml in it.

`<form action = "./login" method="post">` redirects to localhost:8080/login which is a 404. login is in src/action

Comment: so it is enough to declare as `<servlet-class>action.LoginServlet</servlet-class>` in your `web.xml` and it will find the required servlet

Answer (score 0):

Your class is in package `action` so its full name is `action.LoginServlet`. You have configured `src.action.LoginServlet` as the servlet class. Remove `src` from there.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>action.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

This part:

```xml
<form action = "localhost:8080/UserModule/src/action/login" method="post">
```

You have lot of boilerplate code there. Instead, use [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) to add `localhost:8080/webappName` like this:

```xml
<form action = "${request.contextPath}/login" method="post">
```

Since you're using Servlet Specification 2.5, you cannot use `@WebServlet` annotation. So remove it from your Serlvet class. Otherwise, start using Servlet 3.0 or superior by changing the servlet specification in your web.xml

To retrieve **parameters** from the submitted `<form>` use [`ServletRequest#getParameter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)). [`request#getAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) is used in JSP to retrieve attributes to display the data when using Expression Language.

Comment: <form action = "${request.contextPath}/login" method="post"> this only redirected to localhost:8080/login which doesn't exist

Comment: @Obviously then there's something wrong in your application. I have used it several times and works as expected.

Comment: @Obviously please provide info about how you're deploying your web app and what's the distribution of the files.

Comment: I guess. But even when it was hardcoded, and I used `ServletRequest#getParameter` and fixed all the other issues you mentioned, it still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Obviously have you done all the changes I posted here or just a mix of changes based on all the answers?

Comment: I did all the changesyou mentioned here. Also, I posted an image of my directory and distribution.

Comment: @Obviously please post your web.xml as well.

Comment: It is already posted minus this:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   version="2.5">

Comment: Again: post your entire web.xml file in your question. Something's very odd within your project and we don't jave enough info to find that problem

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `@WebServlet("/login")`

This annotation and servlet mapping are interchangeable. So when you use one of these another definition is not required.

In order to use `@WebServlet` webapp's web.xml has to be declared as version 3.0

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

Comment: I know, but I am required to use version 2.5

Comment: Then `@WebServlet` will not work for you. Stick to the servlet mappings inside of your web.xml and also as said by @luiggi-mendoza consider replacig hardcoded localhost:8080 with ${request.contextPath}

Comment: As I mentioned under @luiggi-Mendoza's post, <form action = "${request.contextPath}/login" method="post"> only redirected to localhost:8080/login which doesn't exist