# how can I store the selected value of dropdown list into a variable

Tags: html, jsp

I'm trying to assign the selected value of a dropdown list to a java variable.

The values which the options contain are fetched from the database, but I don't have any clue how to do this.

Say for example I have this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select>
  <option>fetched from database<option>
</select>
<%  //The java code
String select=//how can i get selected value here
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot. Learn about JSP/Servlet lifecycle. You have to have a `<form>`, and a server-side code (an another JSP, or - preferably - a servlet) to process its submission. See e.g. https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/handling-html-form-data-with-java-servlet or http://candidjava.com/tutorial/servlet-form-example/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transfer data from JSP to servlet when submitting HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971877/how-to-transfer-data-from-jsp-to-servlet-when-submitting-html-form)

Comment: Thank you so much you guys answer my question. This is only an example what i want to do. Actually i have a jsp page in that i have select box and the value that select box carry is fetched from the database. What i want that if user select any value from select box than according to that particular value data would be fetch in the html table