# Pre-populating radio buttons in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, radio-button

How can I pre-populate a HTML radio button using JSP, depending on the value in the database?

Answer (score 8):

You just need to let JSP print the `checked` attribute of the HTML `<input type="radio">` element. Easiest way to do that is using the conditional operator `?:` in [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). Here's a kickoff example:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="one" ${bean.foo == 'one' ? 'checked' : ''}/>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="two" ${bean.foo == 'two' ? 'checked' : ''}/>
...
```

Or if you have all available input values in some collection like `List<String>`, then do:

```
<c:forEach items="${foos}" var="foo">
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="${foo}" ${bean.foo == foo ? 'checked' : ''}/>
</c:forEach>
```

Either way, it should ultimately end up as follows in the generated HTML if `${bean.foo}` equals to `"two"`:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="one" />
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="two" checked />
...
```

#### See also:

- [How can I retain HTML form field values in JSP after submitting form to Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937624/how-can-i-retain-html-form-field-values-in-jsp-after-submitting-form-to-servlet/)

Comment: Excellent, thanks again BalusC - I will take this away and use these examples! Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey BalusC, in the second example you provided could you just give me a heads up on what the difference is between ${foos} and ${foo}

I don't think I understand beans & foos enough to be able to follow your examples.

Comment: The `${foos}` is the collection. The `${foo}` is the currently iterated item. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727603/places-where-java-beans-used, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 1):

**Pure JSP Scriplets**

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <% if (resultSet.getString("gender").equals("male")) out.print("checked"); else out.print(""); %> />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <% if (resultSet.getString("gender").equals("female")) out.print("checked"); else out.print(""); %> />
```