# How to prevent retyping typed texts in a textbox during page load

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have a page that handles error when there's one textbox with no content. Now for example I have 3 textboxes then I only put text on the two textbox. When I submit the page an error handler like "*" will appear right beside the empty textbox before the submit procedure. But the contents of the two textboxes were gone so I need to retyped what I've type before. How to prevent this?

Comment: @PaulVargas yes Im using Servlet and JSP

Answer (score 1):

Just redisplay the submitted value from the request parameter map.

```html
<input type="text" name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}" />
```

The [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) is not mandatory for display, but it will save you from [XSS attack holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - the hello world example does exactly the same, perhaps you've never seen our JSP/Servlet/JSTL/EL wiki pages, they're very useful for starters like you
- [How can I retain HTML form field values in JSP after submitting form to Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937624/how-can-i-keep-jsp-form-fields-values-in-the-form-after-submitting-the-form/3937783#3937783)
- [XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java/2658941#2658941)

Comment: an error occured
The attribute prefix fn does not correspond to any imported tag library

Comment: :) Click the "JSTL" link in my answer to learn how to install/import it. Or ask a new question if you really stucks (I'd be surprised though). This is off topic to the current question.

Comment: I solved already by placing `<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>` But how about if Im using a populated dropdown list? with this code `<select name="AccountType">
     <option value = "1">Please Select</option>
         <c:forEach items="${UserItem}" var="AccountType">
             <option value="${AccountType.getRoleId()}">${fn:escapeXml(AccountType.getRoleName())}</option>
         </c:forEach>
     </select>`

Comment: how to implement this with dropdown list?It works fine with my textbox already

Comment: Just let JSP print the `selected` attribute of the HTML `<option>` element dynamically. See the 2nd "See also" link for a concrete example. I do not post links for decoration only.