# JSTL choose tag not working for correctly

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a servlet S which  captures the request parameter of the select field option value from JSP A and stores it in request scope.

```
String test = request.getParameter("option");
    request.setAttribute("select",test);
```

now this servlet S after processing  redirects me  again to same JSP A, now in JSP A I have the same option fields and also I have code something like,

```
 <select name="option">
     <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${select} == All">
      <option id="id" class="cl" value="All" selected>Items</option>                        
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
     <option id="id" class="cl" value="All">All  Items</option>                        
    </c:otherwise>
     </c:choose>
   </select>
```

But for some reasons code never goes into c:when  and it goes directly otherwise section.

Though I have used extensively JSTL,but for some reasons I am unable to get this up.I know value exists in request scope and can see it via c:out tag.Is it possible that we do the post backs to the same page again and again for same session with new values ? Already spend a day on this issue so need third eye to see if I am missing something silly ? Appreciate if someone can take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong.

```
<c:when test="${select} == All">
```

The entire expression has to go inside `${}` and strings needs to be quoted.

```
<c:when test="${select == 'All'}">
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Java EE 6 Tutorial - Examples of EL expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your concrete functional requirement can be solved in a much simpler manner, without that the servlet needs to copy the parameter:

```
<select name="option">
    <option id="id" class="cl" value="All" ${param.option == 'All' ? 'selected : ''}>All Items</option>                        
</select>
```

#### See also:

- [How can I retain HTML form field values in JSP after submitting form to Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937624/how-can-i-keep-jsp-form-fields-values-in-the-form-after-submitting-the-form/3937783#3937783)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: Hah you have magic in your words Balus.Just now I tried again and now its working.I wonder why it did not work me earlier.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note the updated answer for a much simpler manner. As to why it didn't work, apparently you wasn't running/testing the code you thought you was running/testing :)

Comment: Perhaps you are correct Balus, I keep on spending hours doing silly mistakes and maybe I need to focus more.This was crucial piece of work for me as I want to reduce the number of jsp I am developing.I will use your solution of one my other modules.Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest to follow the links. They may contain valuable and enlightening information.

Comment: I will do it Balus.Thanks.