# Values Lost while redirecting to the same jsp ( Without Ajax)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I created a registration page (`r.jsp`) where we can enter user details. Upon clicking the submit button, the servlet is hit and it will perform the business logic. If successful, it redirects to `x.jsp` otherwise if it failed it redirects to `r.jsp`.

The problem I am having is when there is a failure and it redirects to `r.jsp`, data entered by the user is lost. I would like to retain it.

Below is the code I am performing in the servlet:

```
if (appResponse.getMessageStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(AppConstants.SUCCESS)) {
    request.setAttribute("message", appResponse.getMessage());
    url = "/x.jsp";
} else {
    request.setAttribute("message", appResponse.getMessage());
    url = "/r.jsp";
}
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just redisplay the submitted values from the request parameter map in input elements. The request parameter map is in JSP/EL available by `${param}`.

```html
<input name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}" />
<input name="bar" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.bar)}" />
<input name="baz" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.baz)}" />
```

Note that the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) is mandatory to prevent XSS attacks. You can omit it, but then you've a [XSS hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

```html
<input name="foo" value="${param.foo}" />
<input name="bar" value="${param.bar}" />
<input name="baz" value="${param.baz}" />
```

#### See also:

- [How can I retain HTML form field values in JSP after submitting form to Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937624/how-can-i-keep-jsp-form-fields-values-in-the-form-after-submitting-the-form/3937783#3937783)
- [XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java/2658941#2658941)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you aren't redirecting at all. You're just forwarding. You should however actually be redirecting in case of a successful submit to avoid double submits on pressing F5 (as per [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)).

#### See also:

- [RequestDispatcher.forward() vs HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-interface-vs-sendredirect/2048640#2048640)

Comment: I am confused.. pls execuse if my question is wrong.. if I am redirecting to the same jsp page.. how can I set the two values you mentioned.. for instance <input name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}" />  and <input name="foo" value="${param.foo}" />

Comment: The code in the answer is complete as is. Just change your code accordingly based on the answer. You don't need to prepare anything in the servlet. The `${param.foo}` will print the request parameter with name `foo` in JSP. You possibly only need to declare the JSTL `fn` taglib as `<%@taglib%>` in top of JSP. If you've never worked with JSTL before, click the "JSTL" link in my answer to learn how to install/use it. Again, note that you aren't redirecting at all. You're merely forwarding. See also the "See also" link on the subject.