# Default value to select option menu is not recognized

Tags: html, jsp-tags

Below is the code used for simple html and it works:

```
<select id="name" class="state">
    <option value="Brad" selected="selected">
        Brad
    </option>

    <option value="Carol">
        Carol
    </option>

    <option value="Derrick">
        Derrick
    </option>
</select>
```

Is there another method that i can use so that I can set a default value to my select option tag?

In my jsp file:

```
</html:select>
<html:option value="0">--Select--</html:option>
                    <html:option value="Brad" selected="selected">Brad</html:option>
                    <html:option value="Carol">Carol</html:option>
                </html:select>
```

The `<option value="Brad" selected="selected"> Brad </option>` works in simple html. Brad is shown before clicking the dropdown arrow. My problem is that when I used this in my jsp it says that "The attribute is not recognized `<html:option value="Brad" selected="selected">Brad</html:option>`"

Comment: _Is this correct?_  What exactly are you asking?  Does this do what you want?  Is there some problem?  If so, please update your question to indicate what is wrong.

Comment: @EJK. The <option value="Brad" selected="selected">
        Brad
    </option> works in simple html. Brad is shown before clicking the dropdown arrow. My problem is that when I used this in my jsp it says that "The attribute is not recognized  <html:option value="Brad" selected="selected">Brad</html:option>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `JSP` then there is a `tag` for `html-select-dropdown`. Using `<form:select>` tag you can do something like this -

```
<form:select path="country">
   <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---"/>
   <form:options items="${yourList}" />
</form:select>
```

To know more about how to use **jsp select tag** dig deep into this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/).

And for assiging default value take help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657367/selected-value-for-jsp-drop-down-using-jstl).

**Update**
This is how you can include `JSTL` in you `JSP`

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here you see `prefix="form"`, you can name the `prefix` as you want. You can find more detail [here](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-tags-1.html).

Comment: can I do something like this <html:form:select> </html:form:select> ?

Comment: nope. You must follow `JSTL` - jsp standard tag library. Find more about [JSTL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm). Here `form` is not a static key word. You can of course change it as you like while including library

Comment: is there any way that I can use dropdown select option without form tag?

Comment: Of course. You can use plain `HTML` tag the way you are using now. But using `JSTL` tag will save a lot of works for you.

Comment: thanks for sharing these information. It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The ="selected" part is not necessary. Just `<option selected>` will do fine.

```
<select id="name" class="state">
<option selected value="Brad">
    Brad
</option>

<option value="Carol">
    Carol
</option>

<option value="Derrick">
    Derrick
</option>
</select>
```

The value, in this case "Brad", would be passed as a string unless another option is selected.