# concepts about JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I want to understrand what happens when i use JSTL to access maps,in [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet)
in @blausC's answer, he explained what happend, but when i try to use the following code

```
     <c:set var="resultMap" value="validationResults" scope="request"></c:set>
     <c:if test="${resultMap['userName'] != null}">
          ${resultMap['userName'].details}
    </c:if>
```

a confused exception happend

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'userName' not found on type java.lang.String
```

The key of the map should be string, so whay is this exception, i tried the examples in the above question and the same exception,Can some one tell me where I have misunderstanding?

**Edit**:  I populate the map in the servlet and send it to jsp

```
 Map<String, ValidationResult> result = new HashMap<String, ValidationResult>();
 aValidationResult = new ValidationResult();
 check whether the field is valid or not if not fill the map
 result.put("userName", aValidationResult);
 result.put("group", aValidationResult);
```

if map is not empty, return the map to jsp

```
request.setAttribute("validationResults", result);
```

the map is filled when i make server side validation ,

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused because String class does not have a method called getUserName()

Comment: I doubt that would be the reason , but what should I do with map, since it's keys are string??

Comment: How are you populating the resultMap?

Comment: Have you debugged if resultMap is a java.util.Map or java.lang.String?

Comment: @gbakernet, resultMap is java.util.Map

Comment: Can you post how are you inserting values into resultMap?

Comment: @ Enrique-what do u mean with populating the map?

Comment: By populating I mean filling the map

Comment: Try with ${validationResults['userName']

Comment: @Enrique- it works, but what is the difference ,why it doesn't work when i use the variable? Really strange!!

Comment: <c:set var="resultMap" value="${validationResults}" scope="request"></c:set>

Comment: Because in jsp files you reference the variables using the name you specify in the first argument of the setAttribute method.

Comment: @Enrique-I totally agree, but what dose var mean in <set> tag?

Comment: It is used to set the variable name. You can change value="validationResults" with value="${validationResults}" and then use resultMap as your variable name as gbakernet said.

Comment: since i can set the variable name, why cannot i use it instead of the vairable itself??

Comment: You can do It in both ways(validationResults,resultMap), is your choice.

Comment: i want to get why when I use resultMap in my question above doesn't work, even it reference to validationResults?

Comment: Because as gbakernet said you missed to use ${}

Answer (score 3):

`resultMap` is a String because of this line

```
 <c:set var="resultMap" value="validationResults" scope="request"></c:set>
```

You need to use EL to assign the value

```
 <c:set var="resultMap" value="${validationResults}" scope="request"></c:set>
```

**Edit:** The following is working code

```
 <c:set var="validationResults" value="<%= new java.util.HashMap() %>" />
 <c:set target="${validationResults}" property="username" value="Hello World" />
 <c:set var="resultMap" value="${validationResults}" />
 <c:out value="${resultMap['username']}"></c:out>
```

Comment: it doesn't work when i make the value like this value="${validationResults}" ,it works ad @Enriquw answered,but i didn't understand why?