# How to use relative paths without including the context root name?

Tags: jsp, servlets, resources, relative-path, contextpath

To working my static file (CSS, JS) I have to write absolute path like `/AppName/templates/style/main.css`. Is there any solution, that I could write relative path like `style/main.css`?

Comment: Why (and *where*) do you have to write the full path? Nearly anywhere I can think of, `style/main.css` should work. There may well be places where it doesn't, but without your telling people what you're actually trying to do, it's going to be very hit-or-miss whether people can help you.

Comment: I just want to link css file to my jsp page. I didn't write explain, becouse it was the simplest and only use I can image, so I think that everybody guess. Even so: I'm sorry. My mistake...

Answer (score 169, accepted):

If your *actual* concern is the dynamicness of the webapp context (the "AppName" part), then just retrieve it dynamically by [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29).

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/templates/style/main.css" />
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/templates/js/main.js"></script>
    <script>var base = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pages/foo.jsp">link</a>
</body>
```

If you want to set a base path for all relative links so that you don't need to repeat `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` in *every* relative link, use the `<base>` tag. Here's an example with help of [JSTL functions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html).

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<head>
    <c:set var="url">${pageContext.request.requestURL}</c:set>
    <base href="${fn:substring(url, 0, fn:length(url) - fn:length(pageContext.request.requestURI))}${pageContext.request.contextPath}/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/style/main.css" />
    <script src="templates/js/main.js"></script>
    <script>var base = document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].href;</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="pages/foo.jsp">link</a>
</body>
```

This way every relative link (i.e. *not* starting with `/` or a scheme) will become relative to the `<base>`.

This is by the way not specifically related to Tomcat in any way. It's just related to HTTP/HTML basics. You would have the same problem in every other webserver.

#### See also:

- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal)
- [Is it recommended to use the <base> html tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag)

Comment: i dont use pageContext.request.contextPath and i dont see when i really need it i can change the project properties in netbeans for context can you explain more

Comment: ${pageContext... not working for me. Just generates something like localhost:8080/profile/$%7BpageContext.request.context%7D/css/profile/

Comment: @Matt: upgrade to at least JSP 2.0 (released a decade ago). Alternatively, use `<c:out>`. Being a complete ignorant and having very legacy software isn't a fair reason to downvote, btw.

Comment: Thanks Balus for the kind words. How do I tell what version of JSP I have?

Comment: I know this is kinda old, but how would I be able to use ${pageContext.request.contextPath} in a jquery/js variable and use it like that instead of typing out '${pageContext.request.contextPath}' for every link?

Comment: @Vnge: just let JSP print it as a JS variable?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! after a bit of googling i found out i can just print out the variable between ${ } just like the pageContext

Comment: Beware that the `<base>` tag approach can break relative urls such as `<a href="?var=foo">` (yes, these are valid). If placed in for example `/page.html`, they will resolve to `/?var=foo` instead of `/page.html?var=foo`.

Comment: @Natix: Break? It's **intented** as base URL of all relative URLs. See also a.o http://stackoverflow.com/a/1889957 Just don't use it if it doesn't fit your technical implementation.

Comment: It works for me without fn substring part. Is there a need to use fn substring here?

Comment: `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` is now just `${#request.contextPath}`

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox: Nope. That's only the case when you're using some sort of MVC framework on top of JSP/Servlets.

Comment: That base tag is brilliant, had no idea it existed. Thanks for the wonderful answer, again.

Answer (score 21):

Just use [`<c:url>`-tag](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javaserver-pages-3rd/0596005636/re39.html) with an application context relative path.

When the `value` parameter starts with an `/`, then the tag will treat it as an application relative url, and will add the application-name to the url.
Example:

jsp:

```
<c:url value="/templates/style/main.css" var="mainCssUrl" />`
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${mainCssUrl}" />
...
<c:url value="/home" var="homeUrl" />`
<a href="${homeUrl}">home link</a>
```

will become this html, with an domain relative url:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/AppName/templates/style/main.css" />
...
<a href="/AppName/home">home link</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be done simpler:

```
<base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"/>
```

All URL will be formed without unnecessary `domain:port` but with application context.

Answer (score 2):

You start tomcat from some directory - which is the $cwd for tomcat. You can specify any path relative to this $cwd.

suppose you have

```
home
- tomcat
 |_bin
- cssStore
 |_file.css
```

And suppose you start tomcat from ~/tomcat, using the command "bin/startup.sh".

~/tomcat becomes the home directory ($cwd) for tomcat

You can access "../cssStore/file.css" from class files in your servlet now

Hope that helps, - M.S.

Answer (score 2):

Instead using entire link we can make as below (solution concerns jsp files)

With JSTL we can make it like:
To link resource like css, js:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/style/sample.css" />
     <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/sample.js"></script>
```

To simply make a link:

```
     <a id=".." class=".." href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/sample.jsp">....</a>
```

It's worth to get familiar with tags

```
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

There is also jsp method to do it like below, but better way like above:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/style/sample.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/sample.js"></script>
```

To simply make a link:

```
   <a id=".." class=".." href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/sample.jsp">....</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a derivative of @Ralph suggestion that I've been using. Add the `c:url` to the top of your JSP.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:url value="/" var="root" />
```

Then just reference the root variable in your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${root}templates/style/main.css">
```