# JSF: Hyperlink to webpage in /webapp subdirectory

Tags: web-applications, jsf, hyperlink, directory

I have a list of .xhtml pages that I keep in my /src/main/webapp/pages/ folder.
Now I want to create hyperlinks to them.  Currently the only one that works is the default home page: /src/main/webapp/pages/default.xhtml.

```
  <!-- Welcome page -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/pages/default.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- JSF mapping -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

For the others, if I have a link such as:

```
<a href="/pages/page1.xhtml">Page 1</a>
```

I get the following error:

> /page1.xhtml Not Found in
>   ExternalContext as a Resource

My question is:  How do I specify the page I want in a href **relative to the webapp root**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two major things you need to know about relative links (i.e. the ones not starting with http://):

- Relative links starting with a leading slash `/` are relative to the domain root.
- Relative links without a leading slash are relative to request URL (as it is in browser address bar).

---

If the current URL is http://example.com/app and the page contains a link

```
<a href="/pages/page1.xhtml">
```

then it will point to http://example.com/pages/page1.xhtml (fails).

---

If the current URL is http://example.com/app and the page contains a link

```
<a href="pages/page1.xhtml">
```

then it will point to http://example.com/app/pages/page1.xhtml (works).

---

If the current URL is http://example.com/app/pages/default.xhtml and the page contains a link

```
<a href="pages/page1.xhtml">
```

then it will point to http://example.com/app/pages/pages/page1.xhtml (fails).

---

Your problem is that the welcome page is opened by a forward rather than a redirect. This way the request URL as it is in browser address bar stays on http://example.com/app while it is actually displaying the content of http://example.com/app/pages/default.xhtml. To get the links to work in all circumstances you want a link like

```
<a href="/app/pages/page1.xhtml">
```

Thus, including the context path, which is the webapp root. If your sole problem is that you want to include the context path dynamically, then just print [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath())

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/pages/page1.xhtml">
```

#### See also:

- [How to use relative paths without including the context root name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name)