# How to set ContextPath for an image link

Tags: html

i am trying to put context path for an image in HTML.`<img src="/MyWeb/images/pageSetup.gif">`

Here /MyWeb is the ContextPath which is hardcoded. How can i get dynamically.

i am using as `<img src=contextPath+"/images/pageSetup.gif">`but image is not displaying. Is there any option.

Comment: If you're indeed using JSP to generate HTML, you should really add that tag to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write JavaScript in the `src` attribute. To do what you want, try some code like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = contextPath + "/images/pageSetup.gif";
document.getElementById('display').appendChild(img);
```

Here the target; the place where you want to display the image, is a div or span, with the id display.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TQ7X9/)

With HTML, you'll have to take some extra traffic of producing an error, so you can replace the image, or you can send some traffic Google's way. *Please do not use this:*

```
<img src='notAnImage' onerror='this.src= contextPath + "/images/pageSetup.gif" '>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qfeQa/)

**Do not use this.**

Comment: In HTML can i mention like above .

Comment: You can have inline JavaScript in HTML, but it isn't recommended and maintaining it will be difficult. But if you still want to do it anyway, I'll edit my answer and add it there.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry, I lied about the HTML. You can't do what you want with inline JavaScript, unless you're fine with having to load another image first and replacing it.

What is not working?

Comment: It is working in javascript but i am using only html with out js code.

Comment: If you weren't using JavaScript, you shouldn't have tagged it with JavaScript. You can do what you want with server-side code

Comment: But you have hardcoded the context path `onerror='contextPath = "https://developer.mozilla.org/"; `. I dont want this.

Comment: From where do you want to change contextPath? JavaScript, right?

Comment: in html page.Not in javascript.i have the code is `<img src="/myapp/images/pageSetup.gif">` I want `/myapp` in dynamically. my page is print.html.

Comment: On your HTML page, make script tags, and put the JavaScript in there. Make a div tag where you want your image to be displayed, with the id 'display'.
 *Please* learn the language before going off trying to use it.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, "Context path" is a term which is typically used in JSP/Servlet web applications, but you didn't mention anything about it. Your [question history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1018075/mdhar9e) however confirms that you're using JSP/Servlet. In the future, you should be telling and tagging what server side language you're using, because "plain HTML" doesn't have a concept of "variables" and "dynamic generation" at all. It are server side languages like JSP which have the capability of maintaining and accessing variables and dyamically generating HTML. JavaScript can be used, but it has its limitations as it runs in webbrowser, not in webserver.

The question as you initially have will only confuse answerers and yield completly unexpected answers. With question tags you reach a specific target group. If you use alone the `[html]` tag, you will get answers which assume that you're using pure/plain HTML without any server side language.

---

Back to your question: you can use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` for this.

```html
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/pageSetup.gif">
```

#### See also:

- [How to use relative paths without including the context root name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name/4764586#4764586)
- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/servlets-browser-cant-access-css-images-when-doing-a-forward-to-a-jsp/3658735#3658735)

Comment: yes. i will send my entire code to you. I am putting my entire program here.`<html>
<head>
<title>Document Printing Help</title>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store"> 
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<link href="theme/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="helpBody" style="padding-left:10px">
 <img src="/dnweb/images/pageSetup.gif">
 <div style="text-align:center">
 <a href="javascript:self.close()">Close this Window</a>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. You seem to be using JSP. You should tell that in your question. I've already posted an answer how to achieve what you want in JSP.

Answer (score 0):

You must use JavaScript for this.

First, have all images point to some dummy empty image on your domain while putting the real path as custom attribute:

```
<img src="empty.gif" real_src="/images/pageSetup.gif" />
```

Now have such JavaScript code in place to iterate over all the images and change their source to use the context path:

```
var contextPath = "/MyRealWeb";
window.onload = function() {
    var images = document.getElementByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var image = images[i];
        var realSource = image.getAttribute("real_src") || "";
        if (realSource.length > 0)
            image.src = contextPath + realSource;
    }
};
```