# How to set relative URL in servlet jsp

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets, contextpath

I'm jumping into an existing JSP project, using eclipse spring, tomcat 6.

Our project currently has the URL: http:localhost/path1 as its base.

In my index.jsp, when I try to reference .css & .js using: "/css/my.css"

It doesn't append the "/path1" before it, how do I set it up to automatically add that?

And I can't use a variables as I want to these fixed paths inside my .css file to reference images.

I don't want to explicitly type it in as that "path1" will change later.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Servlets - Browser can't access css, images when doing a forward to a JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/servlets-browser-cant-access-css-images-when-doing-a-forward-to-a-jsp/3658735#3658735) and [How to use relative paths without including the context root name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name/4764586#4764586)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context path need to be included at the beginning of the url.  If you don't want to hardcode the context path, you may use the following

```
<%@ include file="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/My.css" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `<c:url value="/css/file1.css" />` - this will append the context.