# Send GET request to Servlet by link

Tags: java, servlets

How can I send data via

```
<a href="#">link<a/>
```

to my servlet so that it executes my

```
protected void doGet()
```

method?

I want to do something like:

```
<a href="article?todo=show_article&article_id=23">link<a/>
```

Comment: do want to pass request parameters also? i see them in ur url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let the link point to an URL which matches the URL pattern of the servlet as configured in `web.xml` or by `@WebServlet` annotation. The example link as you have expects the servlet to be mapped on an URL pattern of `/article`. Its `doGet()` method (if properly `@Override`n) will then be called. The request parameters will then be available the usual way by `request.getParameter()`.

```
String todo = request.getParameter("todo");
String article_id = request.getParameter("article_id");
// ...
```

With the link example as you've given, the JSP page containing the link should by itself however be located in the root folder of the web content or forwarded by a request URL whose base is the context root. Otherwise you need to make the link URL domain-relative by prefixing the URL with `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` like so:

```html
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/article?todo=show_article&article_id=23">link</a>
```

*(please note that you've a syntax error in closing tag, I've fixed it in above example)*

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](http://%3Ca%20href=%22article?todo=show_article&article_id=23%22%3Elink%3Ca/%3E) - Contains some Hello World examples
- [How to use relative paths without including the context root name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name)

Comment: i put my servlet to others and anotated `@WebServlet("/Article")` put domain relative link to href... it looks like: `http://localhost:8080/masite/article/?todo=add_article` but have HTTP Status 404 - /masite/article/. What im doing wrong? My servlets root is :src/servlets/Article.java

Comment: URLs are case sensitive. `/Article` is not the same as `/article`. You need to lowercase the `A` in the URL pattern as follows `@WebServlet("/article")`.