# Simple HTML form submit error

Tags: servlets

I am trying to create a simple HTML form to submit data from JSP to Servlet. I am getting 404 not found exception. My request URL: `http://*****:80**/myapps/more/test.html`

### HTML

```
<form id="userForm" action="/more/loginServlet" method="post">
   <input id="Submit"  value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

web.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>                    
        <servlet-class>com.more1.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/more/loginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Servlet code

---

```
package com.more1;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("===========================");
    // System.out.println(request.getParameter("service_number"));
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your form action URL is wrong. It should stay in `/myapps` context and not go outside. The 404 error simply means that the requested URL does not point to any valid resource. If you have paid close attention to the request URL in the browser's address bar, you should have noticed that `/myapps` part has disappeared.

Fix it accordingly:

```
<form id="userForm" action="/myapps/more/loginServlet" method="post">
```

Or just as follows as you're currently (as per URL in browser's address bar) already sitting in `/myapps/more`:

```
<form id="userForm" action="loginServlet" method="post">
```

Or if you worry about the dynamicness of the context path, inline `HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()` as follows:

```
<form id="userForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/more/loginServlet" method="post">
```

An alternative is to introduce the HTML `<base>` tag.

#### See also:

- [How to use relative paths without including the context root name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name/4764586#4764586)
- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal/3658735#3658735)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, are you absolutely positive that you're reading proper and up to date tutorials when learning servlets? Your `web.xml` root declaration is a Servlet 2.3 one which is more than a decade old already. We're currently already on Servlet 3.0. Start at [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) for some sane Hello World examples and links to sane tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Your app seems to be deployed in the `myapps` context path (th HTML page URL is `/myapps/more/test.html`). But your form submits to `/more/loginServlet`. It should submit to `/myapp/more/loginServlet`.

To avoid hard-coding the context path in your pages, use the JSTL  tag:

```
<form action="<c:url value='/more/loginServlet'/>" ...>
```

or prepend the context path explicitely:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/more/loginServlet" ...>
```