# how to handle base url in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

in asp.net, actually we can use ~/jquery.js means that jquery.js is in the root folder.
but how do we know what is root for jsp?

actually /jquery.js didnot work, suppose we run our app in `http://mypcname.com:8084/131X/`
the ~/jquery.js in asp.net goes to http://mypcname.com:8084/131X/jquery.js but the /jquery.js will go to http://mypcname.com:8084/jqeury.js

Answer (score 1):

Use this to include the JS file.

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery.js"></script>
```

You can get a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name).

Answer (score 1):

With `JSTL` it will be

```
<script src="<c:url value="/path/jquery.js"/>"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use the following code,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jquery.js">
</script>
```

This code :-

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery.js">
```

will do the same thing.

it would take you to the base url of the application http://mypcname.com:8084/

hence http://mypcname.com:8084/jquery.js would load your javascript file.

You will need to insert your javascript file to webapp folder

Answer (score 0):

It has to start with a slash as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
```

It will refer `jquery.js` from the root folder.