# Modifying the path for serving static resources

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, web.xml

How can I force static resources (HTML, CSS, JS) to be served under a different path than what is specified in the /webapp/ directory?

Say I have a resource at the following path in my webapp:

```
/src/main/webapp/client/mypage.html
```

I want clients to be able to access it from the following URL:

```
/myapp-context/v1/client/mypage.html
```

How can I specify a common root URL ("v1") for these resources in my `web.xml` is there a default filter or static resource servlet I can configure which will enable this behavior? Alternately, can I specify a base URL for the entire app beyond the context root?

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen the class [`org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html)?

In the `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/v1/client/*.html" location="/client/pages/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/v1/client/*.js" location="/client/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/v1/client/*.css" location="/client/css/" />
```

If you want to use a `base` tag, see [relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name).

Answer (score 1):

Define

> `<mvc:resources mapping="/v1/client/**" location="/client/" />`

on dispatcher-servlet configuration.

Thanks!