# Servlet Mapping restrics images to be visible

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I tried to map image and other URLs seperately but calling without slashes in ServletPath, it shows images.When ServletPath contains slashes it doesn't allow images to be shown.

JSP :

```
<img src="images/tiger.jpg"/>
```

Servlet :

```
String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
request.getRequestDispatcher("/jspPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>tut.controller.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Results :

```
http://localhost:8888/ServletFilter/url1     ---------------- image visible
http://localhost:8888/ServletFilter/url1/    ---------------- image not visible
http://localhost:8888/ServletFilter/url1/ex  ---------------- image not visible
http://localhost:8888/ServletFilter/url1/ex/ ---------------- image not visible
```

Comment: Make your paths relative the the host by providing the context path in front of them.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks  it helps, Could you make it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a browser sees the following HTML

```
<img src="images/tiger.jpg"/>
```

it sends a request to a URL that is built by taking the path in the `src` attribute and resolving it relative to the current URL. So if you previously sent a request to

```
http://localhost:8888/ServletFilter/url1
```

(which rendered the HTML containing the `img` tag), then the URL for the image would be

```
http://localhost:8888/ServletFilter/images/tiger.png
```

Similarly, if you send your request to

```
http://localhost:8888/ServletFilter/url1/ex
```

the URL for the image will be

```
http://localhost:8888/ServletFilter/url1/images/tiger.png
```

When you prefix the `src` path with a `/`, the URL is constructed relative to the host name. So for

```
<img src="/images/tiger.jpg"/>
```

the request would be sent to

```
http://localhost:8888/images/tiger.png
```

This is not what you want but you can use it to your advantage. JSTL and EL both provide a way to build an absolute (relative to host) URL using the context path of your web application.

```
<c:url value="/images/tiger.png" var="path" />
<img src="${path}"/>
```

Or

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/tiger.png" />
```

This will be resolved to

```
/ServletFilter/tiger.png
```

assuming `ServletFilter` is the value of your web application's context path.

Here's some extra reading:

- [How to use relative paths without including the context root name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to change a mapping for your servlet:

```
 <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
```

That would allow you to get your servlet out of business of static context handling.

It looks like what you're trying to do is to configure Tomcat to serve a static content. While in general this is not a good idea, because of performance impact, in a development environment you still might want to do that. If this is the case, here is a good blog that provides details. It will also allow getting your servlet out of business of static content handling.

http://th1rty7.blogspot.com/2009/05/tomcat-is-often-considered-to-be-too.html

Comment: Have you tried it first? will it work for `http://localhost:8888/ServletFilter/url1/`

Comment: Tried what? Mapping a servlet to a unique path? I do it all the time. After this is done, your servlet will be available at: /<context-path>/myservlet location. Your static context will be available at /<context-path>/.../tiger.jpg location. Most importantly - your servlet will not need to be in a business of static context handler and it normally should not.