# Spring 4 form submission

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I recently upgraded Spring framework from 3.1.2 to 4.1.1. Also upgraded to Tomcat 8 and Java 8. I am also using Tiles 2.2.2.

My web page loads fine using Spring 4 and problem comes when I do a form submission. The URL request changes and leaves out the webapp name.

For e.g., when I do a form submission, 
the URL that is expected is supposed to be http://xx.xx.xx.xx/webappname/createuser/submit.

But the URL changes to http://xx.xx.xx.xx/createuser/submit. And thus, throws a "Requested resource is not available " error.

I did not have this problem when I was using Spring 3.1.2, Tomcat 7, Java 7.

May I know what I am missing?

Thank you,
Whiskers

**EDIT :**

My jsp view goes like

```
<form:form method="post" action = "/createuser/submit" commandName = "createForm" >
 ..... 
< /form>
```

Comment: You can try <c:url value="/createuser/submit"/>

Answer (score 0):

Prepend your hyperlinks with:

`${pageContext.request.contextPath}`

See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name)

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, I wasn't expecting code changes since it works in Spring 3. And I don't wish to have this context path variable repeated for every form that I'm going to create. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your action URL is start with root change your action URL to

```
action = "createuser/submit"
```

Or used `<c:url ... />` tag to create URL and give it to action as shown below

```
<c:url value="createuser/submit" var="myActionUrl" />
<form:form action="${myActionUrl}" .... >
```

May this will help you.

Comment: Your suggestion to change action = "createuser/submit " works for some views. I'm not sure why the upgrade caused this issue. I didn't use to have this problem when I was using Spring 3.1.4. When I changed my libs to Spring 4, I wasn't expecting code changes. Is this expected?