# Path to resourse from generated HTML

Tags: html, css, jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish

My servlet generates an HTML page using page templates. In this page, I have a path to a CSS file, but I could not find the right path. The structure of my project looks like this:

```
root
- src
-- *servlets*
- web
-- WEB-INF
--- CSS
---- style.css
--- template
---- basic.html
```

The **basic.html** template page contains `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`. What do I need to write in `href` for using my CSS file?

My project was created in `IntelliJ` and working on `Glassfish 4`.

Comment: /WEB-INF/CSS/style.css should work

Comment: Move your css folder outside of `WEB-INF`. Files in `WEB-INF` cannot be accessed directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include it from the very begging.

Path would be `/root/src/css/Style.css`

Or you can include it by backtracking the path `../css/Style.css`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name). I find this way the most flexible. You can change your context root without a need to change your code and you do not have to think about constructing relative paths.