# Accessing CSS JS resources in JSP in Mavens (Not using Spring MVC)

Tags: java, jsp, maven, embedded-tomcat-8

I have a JSP/Servlet based web application that uses Maven and has not been implemented using Spring MVC. I'm trying to deploy that to an embedded tomcat container using [webapp-runner](https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner).

The problem is that the css/js and other asset references from the JSP do not load those resources. When I start the application using `java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/myapp.war`, I'm able to access the page using `http://localhost:8080/index.jsp`. However, the resources are not present at `http://localhost:8080/assets/css/sample-css.css` (example reference).

Notice that there is no "webcontext" at all which I'm thinking is the way embedded tomcat works. Any ideas on what may be wrong ?

This is my directory structure:

```
-- src
    --- main
        -- java
            --- <servlet related classes in package folder>
        -- webapp
            -- WEB-INF
                -- web.xml
            -- assets
                -- js
                -- css
                -- fonts
                -- img
            -- index.jsp
```

When I package this application, the WAR, which is present in `<project-dir>/target` looks like this.

```
            -- META-INF
            -- WEB-INF
                -- web.xml
            -- assets
                -- js
                -- css
                -- fonts
                -- img
            -- index.jsp
```

This is the relevant part of pom.xml:

```
  ...
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>                    
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      ...
```

This is how I access resources in the JSP page. I've tried a few styles but nothing seems to work:

```
 <link type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Another way -->
 <link type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I've referred [How to link a web resource file from /main/resources in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051494/how-to-link-a-css-resource-file-in-main-resources-in-jsp) and the resources it points to.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's faced same problem before, he's how I've solved it (temporarily):
I've moved over from Servlet 3.1 to 2.5 and that solved it. I can't understand why, but it now works.