# When I forward from servlet to jsp, it does not output correctly my jsp page. Why?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, bootstrap-modal

I am making this project which forwards values of `Arraylist` from servlet to a jsp. My problem is, whenever I'm directed to the jsp page, my jsp page does not display the correct layout. I'm using `bootstrap` for in my jsp page.

Here is my code:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{                                                                                                                                       
        String goToPage = null;                                                                                         
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8"); 
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String searchedWord = request.getParameter("search").trim();                                                    
        if(searchedWord!=null){
            System.out.println(searchedWord.length());
            //place here the code for searching the pages which contains the typed word     
            PageSearch ps =new PageSearch();
            ArrayList<Result> pages=ps.searchPagesWith(searchedWord);
            System.out.println(searchedWord+" pages found "+pages.size());
            request.setAttribute("pages", pages);   
            goToPage="/TOA/output/searchOutput.jsp";
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();                                                   
            RequestDispatcher rd = context.getRequestDispatcher(goToPage);                                                  
            rd.forward(request, response);  
        }
}
```

My `searchOutput.jsp` is written in with bootstrap. My main problem here is that, the layout does not show properly. It seems that it is not reading the bootstrap. Is there a compatibility problem with jsp and bootstrap? I,m using tomcat. Thank you in advance.

[Here are the list of files in my project.][1]

Where I placed my files are here.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta17J.png
Here is sample code from my searchOutput.jsp. I only included sample code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>      
<%@page import ="java.util.ArrayList" %>        
<%@page import ="backEnd.Result" %>                                 
<jsp:useBean id="pages" scope="request" type="java.util.ArrayList<Result>" />   

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">

<title>Sample</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../img/favicon.png" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,800italic,700italic,600italic,400italic,300italic,800,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">.pie {behavior:url(PIE.htc);}</style> <![endif]-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-scrolltofixed.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.isotope.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/wow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/classie.js"></script>


</head>
<body id="top" class="bodyContent">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container containerMedia">
  <div class="container-fluid navbar-border">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="../index.html"><img src="../img/toalogo.gif"  alt="" style="float: left;"></a>
        <form class="navbar-form collapse searchFormMedia" role="search" style="float: right;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search" name="search">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

<% if(pages!=null) { //display retrieved values%>
        <h1>検索結果 <%=pages.size()%>　あります。    </h1>                                           
        <%for(Result res: pages){
        String link=res.getLink();
        %>  

        <table >                                            
            <tr>                                                                            
                <td><%=res.getTitle() %><br/>
                 <%=res.getSentences() %><br/>
                 <a href="<%=link %>"><%=res.getLink() %></td>                          
            </tr>   

            <br/><br/>                                                              
        </table>                                            
        <%} } else { %>                                         
            <P>何もありません。</P>                                     
 <% }%>


      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right searchFormWeb">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search" name="search">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form> 
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you reading it and how? Please add some more useful information and code.

Comment: Try and get rid of response.setContentType: you are not outputting html directly from the Servlet. That should be on your jsp already and it might clash with bootstrap

Comment: I deleted response.setContentType already. But the output is still the same. The bootstrap layout are not applied. The layout is destroyed. When I input http://localhost:8080/Projectname/TOA/searchOutput.jsp directly in the address bar of the browser , the layout is ok. but when I use the servlet, http://localhost:8080/TOAWebsite/pageServlet, to redirect from searchPage.jsp to searchOutput.jsp, searchOutput.jsp's layout is destroyed.

Comment: Ok. Another thing I noticed is that you are taking the dispatcher from the servlet context rather than the request object: try using the request.getRequestDispatcher instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed context.getRequestDispatcher to request.getRequestDispatcher, as you suggested, still not working.

Comment: You need to tell us what the code of the JSP is (especially the place where you're linking to the CSS files), and where you placed these CSS files in the webapp.

Comment: @sakura there are not compatibility issues between jsp and bootstrap. Probably something is not right in your code. Post your Jsp code and tell us where the bootstrap CSS is located

Comment: I edited my post above to show my jsp code and the location of my css files. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I was able to solve the problem already. I used the method suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name. Thank you!